# Can a fast planetary rotation create a planet with an equatorial continent, preferably with very high mountains and two polar oceans?

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics, geology, tectonics

I’m trying to create a planet with two small polar oceans with equatorial supercontinent in the middle. The land is in turn divided in two by high mountains that act as barrier and a source of water for rivers flowing into oceans.

How the world came to be: during its early youth planet rotated very quickly (few hours) which created substantial equatorial bulge. Continental plates were pushed toward equator creating  multiple uplifting zones, oceanic floors between them were subducted, continental cores mashed together in a crazy jumble of high plateaus and mountain chains with lots and lots of volcanoes. Polar regions were left flat but crisscrossed with mid-oceanic ridges and hotspot archipelagos.

After that initial migration geological activity suddenly slowed down. The resulting uplifted regions were left frozen in place. The byproduct of this is CO2 depletion and very poor biosphere, but it's nothing that can’t be dealt with by terraformers, at least on human timescales.

Thanks to tides and a moon planetary rotation slowed a bit (the day is still 16 hrs. long). Centrifugal pressure weakened, atmosphere on the equator thinned a bit, water flowed toward poles, collecting in polar basins and flooding landmasses that didn’t move toward equator.

Result: polar oceans and equatorial supercontinent with mountains, glaciers and high plateaus in the middle. There are also gigantic valleys, which drain rain and melt water. Because equatorial bulge contributes to the elevation of the supercontinent above sea level, its more northern and southern parts consist of continental slopes and exposed basaltic oceanic floor.

Those ancient oceanic plains are now covered by sediments, and are flat. Very flat. They make a place where winds can blow around the whole world not encountering any obstacle. Coasts are muddy plains, where tides move tens of miles there and back again. Rivers the size of Nile, flowing toward oceans from the equatorial mountains fall from old continental slopes and escarpments in gigantic waterfalls and cataracts.

Does this scenario makes sense and is at least plausible?

(I’ve read this question: [Climatic consequences of two Polar Oceans and a Circumspecting Landmass](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57453/climatic-consequences-of-two-polar-oceans-and-a-circumspecting-landmass) Definitely I’m using it for building climate but first I want to know how to make such configuration of land and water).

Comment: Seems dubious, but I don't really have the time to assemble a decent counter-argument right now :-( I will say that tides in polar oceans about an equatorial continent are likely to be small and uninteresting. Big tides on Earth require resonance patterns ("sloshing") and obstructing landmasses, for example.

Comment: It strikes me that the shape of the planet might have needed to occur before liquid water was around much. Planet formation like this - then a slowing of rotation, then liquid water. Difficult to see how it might ultimately happen without a lot of contrived comets delivering ice. That being said, interesting question.

Comment: I've edited the tags to invite those with a certain expertise, please feel free to revert the edit if you see fit.

Comment: "Continental plates were pushed toward equator" - if continental plates formed before planet's spin-up, we need to explain how they stayed whole during the spin-up event. If continental planes formed after the spin-up event, I'm not sure they want to migrate to the equator after formation, because the entire planet is at hydrostatic equilibrium.

Comment: Continents are not "pushed" towards the equator - that's not how it works. And this implies that your planet has lithospheric plates with continental and oceanic crusts, so what happened to plate tectonics?

Comment: This scenario requires that the planet start with active tectonics and a very high spin rate, followed by enough time for the tectonics to completely stagnate, before then initiating a drastic spin-down of the planet. This will require *several billions* of years. Yet, it must still have significant resources of water despite the absence of vulcanic sources to replenish it, *and* it must acquire a very large moon from somewhere to orbit close-in,to cause the de-spin. Individually everything works, but the timescale and ludicrous unlikeliness of the chain of events is a bit off-putting.

Comment: A better way to do the high-equator-low-polar shape is to make a planet with a thick crust (like Mars), then whack it **very** hard with an impactor on the North pole (like Mars). Then whack it *very* hard again on the south pole (unlike Mars). *THEN* explain where the planet got some replacement water from, to replace what was lost by the succession of very violent impact events. Still requires highly unlikely events, but more plausible as it removes the very difficult timing restraints of the other scenario.

Comment: The fast rotation would likely result in the complete opposite situation I think, with nearly all water on the planet concentrating near the equator due to a combination of centrifugal forces and the tidal pull from the star and the moon, if it exists.

Comment: @DarthBiomech quite correct. That's why the planet needs to start out spinning fast, then solidify its structure, then slow down again. *way* down. But the very thing that can slow it down (a close, large moon), would pull water tides over the rocky bits. SO, once you've slowed it down, you need to somehow dispose of the moon.

Comment: @PcMan wasn't the theia impact hypothesized to bring a lot of water with it, and then provide a handy giant moon to help spin down the earth afterwards? seems a bit suspiciously convenient, but it might do the job...

Comment: Recommended book: ***Mission of Gravity***, by Hal Clement. It's set on an extremely fast-spinning world, and kind of spoils your idea for anyone who's read it. I'd suggest reading it, and then revising your world.

Comment: @PcMan I was saving asteroid impacts for another project. But yes, they could work. Water is not a problem. Let’s say that local Oort cloud had a close encounter with another star. Orbits were perturbed and thousands of asteroids and comets decided to visit inner system. Some of them hit the planet and excavated polar basins, some delivered more water to fill them.

Comment: @John Dallman I dont think Mission Gravity is relevant here. My worldbuilding project is about a planet with a bit more atypical placement of land but which rather conventional. A 16 hour day (present) is short nothing unusual. In comparison Mesklin is totally crazy.

Comment: @PcMan Still I want to give continental migration a chance. I need active tectonics and high rotation on the beginning. Then they must stop. Is there a process that can be responsible for sudden halting of tectonics? Maybe if plates are exceptionally heavy and thick? They could be moved when planet was young and hot, buy after a while tectonic activity become too weak. The plates can still move, supercontinent is breaking up, the equatorial bulge is gradually subsiding under its own weight but those processes are much slower now. Meanwhile the moon is working on slowing the planetary rotation.

Comment: Do you want answers that attempt to create the planet you are envisioning, or do you want an appraisal of your method, or both? Please edit the question to reflect that. (if answers are preferred that retain some parts of your method you might want to put weights on the different aspects - i.e. rotational slowdown is a must, 16h day as well, sleepy tectonics are optional, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: planetogenesis do not work like this.

A fast rotation would change the overall planet shape, deviating from a purely spherical shape. This deformed shape ensures that gravity is directed downwards and not sideway, on all the surface of the planet. As a consequence, there will be no "push" towards the equator for continents or anything else.

Regarding geological activity, shutting it down requires a planet smaller than Earth to happen (considering you are on the same timeline than Earth's). Such cooldown will weaken or remove any magnetic field, making your surface exposed to cosmic rays. And the fact that the planet is smaller implies it may not have as much atmosphere.